# placing the object between subject and the verb

Tags: word-order

I was watching 三体 ep2 and I came across this sentence 我这房子本来买了就是结婚用的  Why did they put 这房子 before 买了?

Answer (score 2):

It is called [topic + comment] sentence structure.

- [这房子] is the topic
- [本来买了就是结婚用的] is the comment

Example:

- [SVO]:我來煮這頓飯 [S = 我; V = 來煮; O = 這頓飯]

*I am cooking this meal*

- [topic + comment]: 這頓飯我來煮 [topic = 這頓飯; comment = 我來煮]

*This meal, I am cooking it*

[topic + comment] structure emphasizes the object.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you also explain what this structure is used for? Is it to emphasize?

Comment: Yes, it emphasizes the object. 本来买了这房子就是结婚用的 doesn't emphasize 这房子 like 这房子本来买了就是结婚用的 does